# Rescuing an ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, rails-activerecord

I am new to ruby and I want to ensure that the combination of three columns in a model will be unique. I tried using validates_uniqueness_of with scopes but it didn't work as intended. So i added a unique index to my db which raises an ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique exception every time an already existing combination of values is saved. The problem is that i am not sure on how to handle the exception. In my controller i altered the update action to:

```
def update

   @patient_history = PatientHistory.find(params[:id])
   @patient_history.save!

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @patient_history, notice: 'Patient history was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @patient_history.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

   end
 end
end
```

This code does not saves the changes and redirects to the show page of my model (:patient_history) with the notice "Patient history was successfully updated". What i am trying to do is for the controller to redirect to the edit page and flash a message at the top of the page about the error (much like validates_uniqueness of would do).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

How did you try using validates_uniqueness_of? You should use this to make sure that this combination is unique, like this:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :column1, :scope => [:column2, :column3]
```

Comment: Yes, that's what i did, but it wouldn't always work properly. So that's why i added the index.

Comment: @Marek Rails validate methods don't prevent race conditions, creating "hardware" index in SQL is always a good idea. Only as it doesn't happen often I usually prefer "let it fail" paradigm, but it depends on your customer.

Comment: I want to make it so that when an error occurs, to redirect the user to the form page, and maybe print a notice that something went wrong. But whatever i tried in the controller it didn't work.

Comment: What what steps did you make and what errors (if any) did you get?